# HTML PHP Video Echo

Tags: php, html, video

i wanted to output the video that the user submitted. But for some reason no of the following attempts worked:

1.

```
echo "<video width='500px'>";
echo "<source type='video/mp4' src=$var autoplay>";
echo "</video>";
```

2. 

```
echo "<video width='500px'>";
echo "<source type='video/mp4' src='../../../clips/<?php echo $_POST[\"type\"]; ?>/<?php echo $_POST[\"name\"]; ?>_<?php echo $_FILES[\"file\"][\"name\"]; ?>' autoplay>";
echo "</video>";
```

code above:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"../../../clips/" . $_POST["type"] . "/" . $_POST["name"]. "_" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$path = "../../../clips/" . $_POST["type"] . "/" . $_POST["name"]. "_" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$var = json_encode($path);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In what way does this fail?  What do these attempts output to the browser in the page source and what's wrong about that output?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what you are doing. `move_uploaded_file` moves the uploaded file to a file path on the server you specified. But the HTML video tag loads the video from an URL. So the path in src needs to be an URL pointing to that path, not a file path. So where you are moving the file needs to be accessible by a url and the src needs to point to that url. So if the clips folder is in the root of your application (next to your index.php) you could use `$src = "/clips/" . $_POST["type"] . "/" . $_POST["name"]. "_" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]`.

Comment: Okay, but the php file is 3 folders above the clips folder so I thought I have to go three folders back with ../
but it's accessible through web. the clips folder is in httpdocs.

Comment: Alright with `$src = "https://domain/clips/" . $_POST["type"] . "/" . $_POST["name"]. "_" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];` the site can be reached but the video is white/transparent. Only the box shadow is visible.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was:

1. I had to enter a complete internet address. (certainly also solvable differently)
2. the filename was too long and could not be specified as source.